# Char array is not empty when should be

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am trying to find the prefix between two words,but it seems like what I have is not correct. First `if(strlen(root) == 0)` always evaluates to 0. Why?

```
The longest common prefix of astrophysics and math is 0��. // <<--- why does this get printed? //
```

Comment: `root` is never initialized to anything in this code if the two words are have no leading similar chars, and is never terminated even if they *have* similar chars. Your while-loop `printf` also invokes undefined behavior as you're sending it non-terminated (and in the first case, completely indeterminate) data for a string format specifier.

Comment: try this first `memset(root,0x00,sizeof(root));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't do this, not before `root` is initialized:

```
printf("root[%d] = %s\n", i, root);
```

The contents of `root` are undefined, by printing it, you are letting `printf()` print whatever garbage value `root` holds, possibly going off bounds, until it finds a null byte.

Your problem is that you are not null-terminating `root`. First, fix the loop. If both words are the same, it will access out of bounds positions. So, your loop condition should be:

```
while(first_word[i] == second_word[i] && first_word[i] != '\0')
```

And then, place this after the loop:

```
root[i] = '\0';
```

Comment: The contents of never be a `NULL` character, because `scanf()` gets input from user.Also, thanks for the answer. I like your explanation.

Comment: @Andy scanf always terminates characters string with a null byte.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your `root` contains garbage values, you need to initalize it
   char root[256 + 1]={0};
2. And after your while loop, 
   `root[i]='\0';`

Now, try it.

Comment: because you need to null-terminate your string. `printf` prints the characters in a string until it finds a `'\0'` aka `null character`.

Answer (score 2):

Strings in C are terminated by the `\0` character. `strlen` returns the number of characters between the first one and that terminator. Since you're building the string dynamically and not appending the terminator, `strlen` will return an arbitrary number of characters between the first and wherever in-memory it happens to encounter the terminator (or just fail with a segmentation fault, for the same reason).

In order to resolve the issue, you should add this treatment:

```
root[0] = '\0';
while(first_word[i] == second_word[i])
{
    printf("root[%d] = %s\n", i, root);
    root[i] = first_word[i];
    root[i+1] = '\0';
    i++;
}
```

Comment: This breaks when `first_word` and `second_word` are the same.

Answer (score 1):

You need to null-terminate root:

```
    while(first_word[i] == second_word[i])
    {
        /* printf("root[%d] = %s\n", i, root);   Can't print root here - it isn't null-terminataed yet */
        root[i] = first_word[i];
        i++;
    }
    root[i] = '\0';
```

Comment: But wouldn't adding `root[i] = '\0';` after the loop disregard all the content of root when it gets printed?

Comment: @Andy No. When you print it, you start from the beginning of `root`. `printf("%s", root)` will print every character in `root` until a null byte is found. You are only placing the null byte in the last position. That's why it's after the loop.